# Instant Articles for WP loader stuck

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I installed the latest version of [Instant Articles for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/) plugin and linked it to my Facebook app.

When I enter the “Add New Post” page, I can see the “Facebook Instant Articles” section but it contains a loader that won’t stop spinning.

The console log has error from admin-ajax.php with this line:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Apparently, it happens on the function `instant_articles_load_meta_box`.

Is this a known issue? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You start by having a look into the server’s error log/PHP error log.

Comment: I get this too, sometimes, with version 3.3.5 of the plugin.

Comment: I noticed that when it happens often is linked to this PHP error message logged: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:f006:15:face:b00c:0:2: Network is unreachable' in /[...]/plugins/fb-instant-articles/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:73"